can't reinstall chromium
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Noticed chromium web page graphics were not displaying correctly so I decided to reinstall. When I tried to use the Ubuntu Software center, uninstall ended with:
unable to remove chromium:
cannot perform the following tasks:

(no further info!)
Used apt to uninstall and did not get any errors. Chromium still shows up as installed in the ubuntu software center.
Subsequently used apt to install chromium-browser and didn't get any errors. However,  chromium won't start, and the software center still can't remove it (same message as before).

Please see this question, you might have the same problem.

Did you actually remove the chromium snap?   as the deb package did nothing more but install the snap package, thus removal of the deb stub then re-install would do nothing... as its the snap package that you need to interact with.

Figured it out. I tried removing the snap version of chromium from the command line and got more info on the problem...
$ sudo snap remove chromium

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap "chromium" (2905) (failed to remove snap "chromium" base directory: remove /home/<home dir>/snap/chromium: directory not empty)
 
$ ls /home/<home dir>/snap/chromium

2295  2319 

After moving '2295' and '2319' to a temporary backup location, the snap tool for uninstalling chromium worked fine. I was then able to reinstall.
